# Как использовать лямбды вместе с boost.asio?

Tags: c++, boost, boost.asio

Как можно заменить все boost::bind на лямбды в коде ниже??? Почему при попытке в функции accept заменить boost::bind на std::bind, компилятор выдает ошибку No matching function for call to 'bind' и как это исправить.

```
void accept();

void out(char* buff){
    printf("%s\n", buff);
    accept();
}

void read(std::shared_ptr<tcp::socket> session){
    char buff[30000];
    session->async_receive(boost::asio::buffer(buff, 1024), boost::bind(out, buff));
    session->close();
}

void accept(){
    std::shared_ptr<tcp::socket> session(new tcp::socket(context));
    acceptor.async_accept(*session, boost::bind(read, session));
}

int main(){
    std::shared_ptr<int> a(new int(5));


    accept();
    context.run();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: здесь смотрели https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/MoveAcceptHandler.html ?

Comment: По пунктам: Почему я не могу передать лямбду в async_accept? - чтобы на это ответить нужно хотя бы видеть ваш код с лямюдой.  std::bind так же не подходят - что значит не подходят? что делать если я принимаю обработчик из вне? - что значит "из вне"?

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch, Когда я пишу лямбду вместо boost::bind, компилятор выдает ошибку, если я использую std::bind вместо boost bind, компилятор так же выдает ошибку. Из вне означает, передать обработчик например, в функцию accept, как это сделать, чтоб его в последствии можно было передать в async_accept,

Comment: каждый раз, когда Вы пишете "выдает ошибки", приводите эти самые ошибки. Мало чего там бывает. Может у Вас компилятор от c++/cli

Comment: @DenverToha во-первых привидите код ваших лямбд, во-вторых, привидите код ошибок. И не могу не заметить, что согласно вашей формулировке, обработчик всегда передается "из вне"

Comment: @KoVadim, при замене boost::bind на std::bind компилятор пишет No matching function for call to 'bind'. Все необходимые заголовки подключены, странно что в функции read он не ругается а в accept ругается.

Comment: @KoVadim, вот пример как я хочу использовтаь лямбду

void accept(){
    std::shared_ptr<tcp::socket> session(new tcp::socket(context));
    auto arg = [&](){
        char buff[30000];
        session->async_receive(boost::asio::buffer(buff, 1024), std::bind(out, buff));
        session->close();
    };
    acceptor.async_accept(*session, arg);
}

Comment: я не настолько хорошо знаю буст.азио, но вижу, что сигнатура функции похоже не подходит.

Comment: @KoVadim, почему она подходит в случае boost bind, но не подходит в случае std::bind

Comment: я пока не знаю, но Ваш код у меня не компилится. А подбирать все incude мне лень

Comment: @KoVadim, чтоб компилилось нужно добавить это #include <iostream>
#include "functional"
#include "boost/asio.hpp"
#include <boost/bind/bind.hpp>
boost::asio::io_context context;
using boost::asio::ip::tcp;
const uint16_t port = 8000;
tcp::acceptor acceptor(context, tcp::endpoint(tcp::v6(), port));

Comment: почему она подходит в случае boost bind, но не подходит в случае std::bind - а кто вам сказал, что подходит в случае boost::bind? В конце-концов вы приведете текст ошибок или нет? И сделайте, пожалуйста, это в вопросе - коментарии не для кода предназначениы

Comment: что касается `No matching function for call to 'bind'` - мой хрустальный шар показывает, что вы не подключитили `functional`

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch, подключил, std::bind работает, если использовать его в функции read, но не работает если использовать в accept

Comment: @DenverToha блин, ну вот сколько раз вам нужно повторить: приводитп текст ошибок!!! Хрустальный шар не всегда работает

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch, так уже привел No matching function for call to 'bind'

Comment: @DenverToha компиляторы более многословны и выдают более одной фразы за раз. Так что потрудитесь привести ошибку

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch, к сожалению, это весь текст

Comment: @DenverToha к сожалерию врят ли кто-то вам сможет помочь в вашей проблеме, если вы не можете банально привести текст ошибки